# Custom Task button "Log a Phone Call" in salesforce.com

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I'd like to create a custom task button that would create a new activity or task and default subject and a custom field "Activity.Type__c" to "Phone Call" when clicked.

I got as far as defining the button, but need some pointers on what the content source and the actual code should be.

Sample code and/or links to tutorials are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the URL for the button to have GET parameters with Ids matching the fields on the page, and then their values. So, look at the id of the custom field in the HTML, it'll be an 18 character string (e.g. 00ND0000003IyoE). Then set that in the URL with `?00ND0000003IyoE=Phone%20Call`. Note: I'm using %20 for the space.

Comment: Thank you, could you also provide a full example of the link?

Comment: Couple of steps, go to create a new object of whatever is it you want to add the button to. The url will be something like `/a01/e`. So copy that.

Comment: Next view the HTML source of the page and see get the ID of the field you want to set as a default. Lets say it's `0000myfield`. Copy that too. Now the URL for your button will be `/a01/e?0000myfield=value` where value is what you want it to default to. Go to the setup for your object, scroll down create a URL button with the URL, and then add the button to a page layout.